# How to capture screen and audio input and push to rtmp server?

Tags: rtmp, avconv

I use avconv on ubuntu,I found this command

```
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+0,0 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -pre:0 lossless_ultrafast -threads 0 video.mkv
```

to save as a file, and this command

```
avconv -i ./test.m4v -re -c copy -f flv "rtmp://localhost/livestream"
```

to push live stream.

How can I combine them together?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should ask such questions on video.stackexchange.com and not here.

Secondly, let's take apart the two commands that you have found:

- `-f alsa` - format for the input is `alsa`
- `-i pulse` - you are reading `pulse` (the pulseaudio driver)
- `-f x11grab` - planning to read from the screen on x11
- `-r 25 -s 1280x720` - rate and size of the incoming video stream
- `-i :0.0+0,0` - this selects where the incoming video comes from
- `-acodec libfaac` - here the output options start, you're setting audio code to libfaac, or at least trying to... since this option has been deprecated long time ago, currently `-c:a` would be used
- `-vcodec libx264` - setting video code, except that you should be using `-c:v`
- `-pre:0 lossless_ultrafast -threads 0` - some sort of parameters about how encoding should be done
- `video.mkv` - this is the output file

And the second one

- `-i ./test.m4v` - the file you're reading
- `-re` - "Read input at native frame rate"
- `-c copy` - do not reencode, but simply pipe as is
- `-f flv` - the container format
- `"rtmp://localhost/livestream"` - where you're planning to write all that.

When you understand that, it should be clear that what you are planning to do is to use the input and encoding part from the first command, and the format and output from the second one.

Here i didn't have time to check that everything that you found is working, you should do that yourself.